# VSCode Remote Container - Error: ENOSPC: No space left on device

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have been using the [VSCode Remote Container Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) for some time without issue. But today when I tried to open my project the remote container failed to open with the following error:

```
Command failed: docker exec -w /home/vscode/.vscode-server/bin/9833dd88 24d0faab /bin/sh -c echo 34503 >.devport
rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, mkdir '/home/vscode/.vscode-server/data/logs/20191209T160810
```

It looks like the container is out of disk space but I'm not sure how to add more.

Upon further inspection I am a bit confused. When I run `df` from in the container it shows that I have used `60G` of disk space but the size of my root directory is only ~`9G`.

```
$ df
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          63G   61G     0 100% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1        63G   61G     0 100% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /sys/firmware

$ du -h --max-depth=1 /
9.2G    /
```

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you show `docker info`, please? Blind guess: all docker images (old,unused included) are stored somewhere on `/`, so you should to clean them: `docker system prune`.

Comment: @JanGaraj the `df` and `du` commands shown were run from in the container. My host machine has plenty of space left.

Comment: `docker info`, please? Default container rootfs size is only 10GB (devicemapper), so it will be interesting to see how is configured storage driver (it looks like overlay).

Comment: @JanGaraj I added docker info output

Comment: Could you check disk space for the volume where is `/var/lib/docker` located?

Comment: @JanGaraj How do I find it. `/var/lib/docker` is not on my system

Comment: df /var/lib/docker

Comment: `df: /var/lib/docker: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `docker system prune --all` if you don't see any container or images with `docker ps` and `docker images`, but be careful it removes all cache and unused containers, images and network. `docker ps -a` and `docker images -a` shows you all the containers and images including ones that are currently not running or not in use.

Check the docs if problem persists: [Clean unused docker resources](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_cleaning-out-unused-containers-and-images)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like all docker containers on your system share the same disk space. I found two solutions:

1. Go into Docker Desktop's settings and increase the amount of disk space available.
2. Run `docker container prune` to free disk space being used by stopped containers.

In my case I had a bunch stopped docker containers from months back taking up all of the disk space allocated to Docker.